# How do you define the length of a parameter in ESC/POS?

Tags: printing, thermal-printer, escpos, pos

I need to be able to print Hebrew characters on my Epson TM-T20ii. I am trying to get my printer to switch to character code page 36(PC862) using

`ESC t36`

for some reason the printer is switching to code page 3 and then printing the number 6.

Is there a way to let the printer know that the 6 is part of my command?
If you know of a different workaround please comment below.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a mistake, you aren't meant to replace n with an actual number.

The proper syntax in your case would be `←t$`

Explanation: the manual says "ESC t n", n referring to the page sheet, however you don't replace n with a number rather with the ASCII character *n*, so in your example 36 = $ because $ is the 36th character on the ASCII table.